# Integration testing user update controller with MockMvc

Tags: spring, integration-testing, mockmvc

I am trying to test to see if the logic behind the user update controller is functioning correctly by creating some simple integration tests using MockMvc.

I am updating users credentials, for security reasons the password doesn't get returned in the response dto, this way I can limit the amount a password is exchanged from the client and the server.

The problem is, how do I test that the password was actually updated before the test is rolled back?

I tried manually performing a login before the test is finished, and if the login fails with the original credentials, the password was updated.

The simple part of the test is straight forward:

```
@Test
  void WhenUserIsAdmin_UserCanUpdateAllFields() throws Exception {

    updatedUser.setPassword("newPassword");

    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(updatedUser);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = TestRequestFactory.authorizationFactoryPUT(URI, "admin");
    mockMvc.perform(builder.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonString))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.firstName").value("admin2"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.surnamePaternal").value("admin2"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.surnameMaternal").value("admin2"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.roleName").value("User"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.roleType").value("ROLE_USER"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.created").isNotEmpty());
  }
```

and the Factory looks like this

```
public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder authorizationFactoryPUT(String url, String user)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    return MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(url)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, doLogin(user, user));
  }

static String doLogin(String user, String pass) throws JsonProcessingException {
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(user, pass);
    String resultAsJsonString = restTemplate.postForEntity(loginServer + "/login", loginRequest, String.class).getBody();
    LoginResponse loginResponse = mapper.readValue(Objects.requireNonNull(resultAsJsonString), LoginResponse.class);
    return loginResponse.getTokenType() + " " + loginResponse.getAccessToken();
  }
```

and inside of the same test I tried

```
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(user, pass);
String resultAsJsonString = restTemplate.postForEntity(loginServer + "/login", loginRequest, String.class).getBody();
LoginResponse loginResponse = mapper.readValue(Objects.requireNonNull(resultAsJsonString), LoginResponse.class);
```

and if the response fails whilst mapping or the http response code is a 401. Then all is ok, but it seems like the data is never persisted to the database.

Comment: Do you have `@Transactional` on your `@Test`?

Comment: Please post full Testcase

Comment: I have updated my question to include a bit more detail on the factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have test case with @Transactional on top this means that this transaction will never be commited as this is `@Test`.

So when you make `http` call by `restTemplate` the transaction is not commited  and the changes will not be visible for the `/logIn` endpoint. (this is normal http request and is not bounded with the `@Test` `@Transactional`)

You can use `mockmvc` instead of `RestTemplate` to call login endpoint and assert the results. Both `mockmvc` will be bounded by same transaction and changes will be visible.

**EDIT**

In case /login is not part of this service than you should user repository to get password from db at some point. `repo.findUserByFirstName` maybe and verify what you need. Since this call will be in same transaction the result will be valid also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it helped understand how MockMvc works internally, I should have explained that I am using the RestTemplate because the login endpoint is part of the gateway and not the users-service that controls user information

Comment: from ongoing transaction you can freely select anything from database and verify no need to call external service.

Comment: Also test should be autonomous there should not be calls to external services/databases. You should test your own code. It's good practice to use embedded database for testing and mock all external calls with appropriate ways